# Why can't I convert_into in the tabula function of python?

Tags: python, error-handling, tabula

I'm trying to use the code convert_into in tabula module and I'm getting an error.

AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'convert_into'

pip install tabula
pip install tabula-py

import tabula
my file= f
tabula.convert_into(....

and I'm getting that error please help.